# How Can I use a private method inside the class in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How Can I use a private method inside the class in VBA?

I wrote private procedure inside class

```
Private Sub setStartShift()
```

But I cannot call it in this way:

```
this.setStartShift
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

Use `Me`, not `this`, to access the current instance - but only the public interface is exposed through `Me`.

Use unqualified member calls to access the private interface.

```
Public Sub DoSomething()
    DoSomethingInternal ' implicit call
    'Call DoSomethingInternal '' explicit call (obsolete)
End Sub

Private Sub DoSomethingInternal() ' not accessible through public interface
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

---

#### Why though?

In VBA, the essence of `this` is embodied in the `Me` implicit identifier: it refers to the current instance of the class, as exposed through its default interface. In other words if you're writing a method in a class module named `Class1`, then in that procedure `Me` refers to the current instance of `Class1`, *as if you were accessing it from the outside*:

[image: Compile error: Method or data member not found]

The [specifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156851.aspx) tell us how `Me` really works (emphasis mine):

> Within the `<procedure-body>` of a procedure declaration that is defined within a `<class-module-code-section>` the declared type of the reserved name `Me` is the named class defined by the enclosing class module and the data value of `Me` is an object reference to ***the object that is the target object of the currently active invocation of the function***.

Further, from [section 5.3.1.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee199631.aspx):

> Each procedure that is a method **has an implicit ByVal parameter** called the current object that corresponds to the target object of an invocation of the method. The current object acts as an anonymous local variable with procedure extent and whose declared type is the class name of the class module containing the method declaration.

In other words when you do this:

```
Dim foo As Class1
Set foo = New Class1
foo.DoSomething 42
```

How the compiled code actually runs is closer to something like this:

```
Dim foo As Class1
Set foo = New Class1
Class1.DoSomething foo, 42
```

And since the parameter's type is *the class name of the class module containing the method declaration*, the member *must* exist on that class' `Public` interface for the member call to be resolvable at compile-time.

["Understanding 'Me' (no flowers, no bees)" on my "Rubberduck News" blog](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/09/05/understanding-me-no-flowers-no-bees/)

Comment: Now I understand
Thanks for help